# Find all Obj who's Delivery Radius is within Geocoded Address

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-geocoder

I wrote a function in my Rails app that has isn't passing a smell test and I'm unsure how to refactor.

Currently, a user is able to enter in an an address into a form and my goal is to spit out any delivery companies that are within a given delivery radius.  Right now that looks like this:

```
class Dealers < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :delivery_radius, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

so a search comes into my controller and I call a method I wrote (`available_deliveries`) like this:

```
  @dealers = Dealer.available_deliveries(Geocoder.coordinates(search_params))
```

`search_params` is just street, city & state.

my `Dealer#available_deliveries` method looks like this:

```
  def self.available_deliveries(geo)
    dealers = []
    Dealer.all.each do |dealer|
      if dealer.distance_from(geo) <= dealer.delivery_radius
        dealers << dealer
      end
    end
    dealers
  end
```

YIKES that's ugly.  I'm unsure how to do a `where` SQL statement to get the same results...

Comment: How `distance_from` looks like?

Comment: Hi @uhn-nohn `distance_from` is a Geocoder method that does this: `obj.distance_from([40.714,-100.234]) # distance from arbitrary point to object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your backing database, I suggest you use its abilities for indexing according to geo-spatial distance.

[Postgresql](http://johanndutoit.net/2013/01/07/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres.html):

> ## Finding Records in a Radius
>
> Another great function provided by these extensions is the
>   `earthbox(lltoearth($latlngcube), $radiusinmetres)` this function allows
>   us to perform a simple compare to find all records in a certain
>   radius. This is done by the function by returning the great circle
>   distance between the points, a more thorough explanation is located at
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatcircle.
>
> This could be used to show all events in our current city.
>
> An example of such a query:
>
> ```
> SELECT events.id, events.name FROM events WHERE earth_box( {current_user_lat}, {current_user_lng}, {radius_in_metres}) @>
> ```
>
> ll_to_earth(events.lat, events.lng);

[MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041104/geo-distance-mysql):

> We are using `double` to store `latitude` and `longitude`. In addition we
>   precompute (by triggers) all values which are precomputable when
>   looking at one point only. I currently don't have access to the
>   formula we are using, will add this later. This is optimized for an
>   optimal speed / precision balance.